# Can't restore LVM Logical volume configuration - missing PV

Tags: configuration, lvm, restore

I had a VG with 3 pvs. The VG had one LV using all three PVs. Then one PV (hdd) died. I wanted to try to recover whatever I could. So the first thing I needed to do was to remove the missing PV from the LV/VG. Following instructions I found via googling, I used vgreduce to remove that PV. But, as I learned, that removed the LV as well. I am now trying to restore the original configuration, the one before the vgreduce, to use vgchange instead. I am using vgcfgrestore -f , where the archive file is the one created before the vgreduce. But I keep getting "Cannot restore Volume Group VGR with 1 PVs marked as missing".

Is the LV recoverable? If so how?

Any help greatly appreciated.

TIA

ken

Answer (score 1):

Linux LVM does not remove PVs with LVs on them by default. It needs all the extents for the LVs to have good integrity.  `vgreduce --force`  might remove LVs though, it disables several safety checks. Be *very* specific and careful in what options you use. Log your terminal sessions.

Plan your recovery. Find any backups that exist of this data. Estimate how valuable it is to the organization, and how long it would take to recreate. If there are no backups, consider getting an estimate from a professional data recovery service.

Attempt to image the failed drive to a good one of the same size. If doing it yourself, with an error tolerant tool like `dd_rescue`.  Beware that in some cases further use can damage the media further, if not already dead. Data recovery services might be able to do surgery on it in an attempt to get data back.

If you manage to image it, the new disk will have the old PV's identification.  Add the new device back in.  `vgextend --restoremissing $PV`  As you reduced LVs away,  this would be the time to try `vgcfgrestore --file` again, to get back to before you did that.

Should all attempts fail and you accept data loss, consider replacing the failed PV with a new empty drive. Almost certainly this will corrupt your data. How exactly the corruption manifests depends on file system and such. But its something to try. `man vgcfgrestore` describes the procedure:

> To replace PVs, `vgdisplay --partial --verbose` will show the UUIDs
> and sizes of any PVs that  are  no  longer present.  If  a PV in the
> VG is lost and you wish to substitute another of the same size, use
> `pvcreate --restorefile filename --uuid uuid` (plus additional
> arguments as appropriate) to initialise  it  with  the  same UUID  as
> the missing PV. Repeat for all other missing PVs in the VG.  Then use
> `vgcfgrestore --file filename` to restore the VG's metadata.

In a less degraded scenario without missing PVs, `pvmove` will move extents between PVs, and can be used in storage migrations.

Going forward, to have volume groups survive hard drive loss, consider adding redundancy. Either below LVM with PVs from LUNs of an array, or at the LVM layer.  See man pages `mdadm` and `lvmraid` respectively, for software solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link is the answer to your question
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47380/where-does-lvm-store-data